# Objective-C method not being called

Tags: objective-c, iphone, methods

It's either because of the fact I'm tired or because I'm doing it wrong, but for some reason I can't get it to call a method.

Here's what I'm trying to call:

```
-(void)newHighScore:(int)d
```

Which right now just does an NSLog saying "yea I'm working!"

I'm calling it like this:

```
[highscore newHighScore:score];
```

highscore is what I called the HighScore class in the .h, and score is an int with the score.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you initialize the highscore object?

The newHighScore is an instance method, so it needs an instance of that object?

You should have, before you call the method, something along the lines of

```
HighScore *highscore = [[HighScore alloc] init];
```

Otherwise, highscore will be nil, and any messages passed to nil simply do nothing.

Comment: yep.  Just before I logged in to SO I was looking over my code again, and I realized I didn't include it, and it was nil.  Mental note: don't Tiredacode

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, and this is likely correct, that highscore is nil.